# If else structure

Tags: c#, if-statement

Hey all I’m having a hard time structuring my if else statement. I am checking for eligibility based of age and experience. I need to check that age is over 60, experience is over 20. If either is false I need to show that (which I have completed) but I need to also display they are both false if so. Obviously I could do this with a lot of redundancy but what the simplest nested if else structure I could use? Thank you!!!

Just regular if else

Comment: Please show the code.

Comment: "lot of redundancy" - so? Is it an actual problem except for readability? If you have many criteria a common approach is to create objects for each type of check. Something like a interface with a method: `bool IsValid(Person p, out string failReason)` That way you can have a list of checks to loop over.

Answer (score 2):

If all you had to do was check all the conditions at once, then:

```
if ({expr0} && {expr1} && {expr2} && ...)
{
    // TODO: all good, do the thing
}
else
{
    // TODO: tell them that we couldn't, but not why
}
```

would do; but it sounds like you need to provide feedback per test. The *simplest* approach is probably to validate each individually:

```cs
bool valid = true;
if (age <= 60)
{
    valid = false;
    // TODO: show feedback about age
}
if (experience <= 20)
{
    valid = false;
    // TODO: show feedback about experience
}
// ... (any other tests)

if (valid)
{
    // TODO: all good, do the thing
}
```